# D365 Dynamics Customer Engagement / CRM V9 - Populate the appropriate value in Modified By field

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

It is about the case entity. There are various synchronous and asynchronous workflows and plug-in setup on UPDATE of the case record.

So, if someone modifies any of the fields or any other things on the case record, the Modified By field doesn't get populated with that user name rather it gets populated with either SYSTEM or the ADMIN user, who modifies the record via process or plug-in.

The client would like to see the actual user name who updates the record in Modify By field, can anybody advise further on this?

One possible solutions would be creating a new custom field and populating the user name in this field and consider that to understand who changed the record.

Does anyone have any other better solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your Plugins and Workflows getting executed in Admin user context rather than `calling user` context. That's why you're seeing this behavior. This may be due to some security role privilege limitation, verify it - if not you can try the `calling user` context in Plugin steps & Workflow design.

[image]

[image]

Furthermore, you can initiate the **Organization service** based on calling user, initiating user or any particular Admin user in C# code implementation while doing `service.Update()`.

Read more about [Plugin step user context](https://www.inkeysolutions.com/blogs/execute-a-plugin-in-the-context-of-the-logged-in-user-or-calling-user-or-system-user-in-microsoft-dynamics-365/) and [Workflow user context](https://garethtuckercrm.com/2013/12/06/crm-2013-new-features-using-real-time-workflow-for-validation-rules/)